# Proving a function is smooth, and has derivatives of all orders at 0

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, polynomials

*Let*

$$f(x)= \begin{cases}
e^{-1/x}\quad &\text{for } x>0 \\
0\quad &\text{for } x\leq 0.
\end{cases}
$$

*Show that $f$ is smooth and $f^{(n)}(0)$ = $0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}.$*

My professor gave us a hint, which was to show that $f^{(n)}(x)$ = $P_n(1/x)e^{-1/x}$ for $x>0$, and some polynomial $P_n$. However, I've been trying to find the actual formula for the polynomial and can see the form it should take, but cannot figure out the polynomial itself. Is it necessary to actually define the polynomial, or just to prove that such a polynomial exists?

If the latter is the case, how would I go about proving this?

Comment: @GNUSupporter Didn't see that question originally,  thank you!

Comment: Thanks to [Approach 0](https://approach0.xyz/search/).

Comment: $f^{(n+1)}(x) = e^{(-1/x)}*((1/x^2)*P_n(1/x) - (1/x^2)*P_n'(1/x))$

Comment: @antsatsui ah, so you can use this to prove it inductively. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you can prove both parts by induction. Notice $P_{n+1}(1/x) = (1/x^2)*P_n(1/x) - (1/x^2)*P_n'(1/x)$ is the recursive formula for every polynomial (implies existence of all derivatives). For the latter part, $f^{n+1}(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f^n(0)}{x}$. Let $u = 1/x$ then it is equivalent to look at $\lim_{u \to \infty} \frac{u*P_n(u)}{e^u}$.